# How to use .http file outside visual studio - e.g. Azure Pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines, integration-testing, continuous-deployment, web-api-testing

Is .HTTP file format Visual Studio specific, or is there some multi-plaftorm tooling for it?

How do I integrate it to CI/CD pipeline?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pipeline task out-of- the-box to call the request directly from the .http file.

As a workaround you may convert your request into a PowerShell script using [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4).

Besides, you may also consider using the [Invoke REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task in an [agent-less job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases#server-jobs).